# 600VDC measurement with Arduino (voltage divider)

Tags: analogread, voltage-divider

I need to detect quick (~200ms) voltage drop, so I am thinking of making an oscilloscope with Arduino. Problem is - can I reliably read 600V DC voltage and what resistor values should I choose for voltage divider? Can I apply same rules as for lower voltage (150k and 1k ohm)?

Comment: I think this would be better suited for electrical stackexchange

Comment: I'm probably going to regret asking, but: what is the actual application of this?

Comment: Welcome to SE/Arduino! -- Is the ground (reference) of the 600 VDC safe to touch? Like, you are measuring tram (public transport) power?

Answer (score 0):

I think first of all you need a circuit to bring down the voltage to about 5volt otherwise 600volts will blow up your Arduino.
[image: voltage reader]

Here is the code

```
int vin=A2;
int inputstate;
float inputvalue;

void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(vin,INPUT);
}

void loop()
{
inputstate=analogRead(vin);
inputvalue=(inputstate*5.5)/(11.7)/0.8;
Serial.println(inputvalue);
}
```

It might works but it is hard for me to get the actual calculation  but you need to change this for your liking make this calculation,,

***inputstate(which is your analogread pin maximum readings (1023)) × 5.0(you need to cange this on your calculation) / 11.7( or any number it can divide to give you 600.0)***
So your calculation will be

***1023 × 5.0 (or whatever number) / 11.0(or whatever number to get 600.0)***

Once you have gotten your right calculation
You input  the numbers you calculated with in place of 5.0 and 11.0

You can remove 0.8 i added it base on my calculation to get 600.0.

Comment: I have put 1Mohm and 10Kohm resistors, which seem to work.

Comment: This should work but, if the 119 kΩ resistor ever fails short, one may end up with deadly voltage reaching the computer (and the user). It would be wise to split the circuit into a possibly-having-unsafe-voltage part, and a safe part, with some galvanic isolation between them. And have the design checked by someone qualified to handle high voltages.

Comment: @EdgarBonet nice idea edgar, 600v dc is deadly and might cause damage to not only the computer but also to the user

Comment: Try to design in an opto-coupler instead of using solutions which results in the Arduino sharing a ground and otherwise directly connected with a 600 Volts DC system. This will, however, detect only 600V or zero. For intermediate voltages it is not appropriate. There are, however, methods of using a PWM signal to represent a voltage which can cross an opto-coupler.

Comment: If the ground (reference) of the 600 VDC is safe to touch, multiple resistors in series are a good and common solution. Only one of them will break or get short, leaving the others as safety measure.

Comment: Be aware that resistors have a maximum voltage rating. It is normal to use a chain of smaller resistors to spread the voltage between them. For instance ten 75V 100kΩ resistors in series would give 1MΩ at 750V rating. Assuming you design your PCB layout with the correct clearances etc. At 600V you need to be *very* careful with your PCB design.